# Skype launched from WPF C# Help Button hangs desktop computer when call terminated

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, desktop-application, skype4com

I have a standalone desktop WPF C# application with a HELP button that initiates a Skype phone call to my help desk. If the help desk terminates the call everything works fine.  However, if the customer (the app user) terminates the call the application hangs. I have pieced the following code together from searching many web sources.

```
private void btnSkype_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Skype oSkype = new Skype();
        if (!oSkype.Client.IsRunning) {
            oSkype.Client.Start(false, false); //minimized, no splash      
        }
        try {
            oSkype.Attach(5, true); //wait for client to be connected and ready
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
        Call oCall = oSkype.PlaceCall("SRGWJG");
        do
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        } while (oCall.Status != TCallStatus.clsInProgress);
        oSkype.Client.Focus();
        oCall.StartVideoSend();
        do
        {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        } while (oCall.Status == TCallStatus.clsInProgress);
        oSkype.Client.Minimize();                     
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to format the code.  I'll try again

Comment: You should *not* just copy-paste code, you should understand what it does. Calling `Thread.Sleep` in a loop *will* freeze the application, possibly preventing it from updating the `oCall` status. You should listen to the `oCall` object's events instead.